# React ref callbacks behaves differently with useCallback hook?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

In my React component with useCallback hook like below. I wrapped a onClick event handler with useCallback also wrapped a ref callback with useCallback. While clicking on the button, it would change the state value hence cause the component to re-render. It's observed that the console log inside the onClick event handler "handleOnClick" is executed at every re-render, whereas the console log inside the ref callback "divRefCallback" only executed once.

I can understand why the handleOnClick is executed at each re-render, because useCallback will only avoid **recreating** the function, but will NOT avoid **re-executing** the function. However, I cannot understand why useCallback works differently with ref callback, because in this example, it doesn't re-create the function but also not executing the logic inside the callback as well.

I am wondering why it's behaving like this? Is there any other scenario where useCallback would avoid **re-executing** the callback logic?

Is there any official document to explain this? Thanks in advance for any insights!

```
function UseCallbackDemo() {
  const divRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  console.log("**** re-render component");
  const divRefCallback = React.useCallback((div) => {
    if (div) {
      divRef.current = div;
    }
    console.log("*** divRefCallback");
  }, []);

  const handleOnClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('**** handleOnClick');
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={divRefCallback}>{count}</div>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>click</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Please test the code here: https://playcode.io/1529685

Comment: `It's observed that the console log inside the onClick event handler "handleOnClick" is executed at every re-render`: this is not true.  "handleOnClick" is executed when you click the button and the state change causes the re-render. So, it is a side-effect of button click and not of re-render.

Comment: I agree with that, but I think that doesn't matter, we can just remove the button and the handleOnClick. What I am trying to understand is the divRefCallback, because it's not execute the callback at all at each re render, but only for the 1st time.

Comment: Thats because the ref callback is only called when the **component mounts** and not in subsequent re-renders. This ensures that the reference you are storing via `useRef` does not change over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback):

> Instead of a ref object (like the one returned by `useRef`), you may pass a function to the ref attribute.
>
> ```
> <div ref={(node) => console.log(node)} />
> ```
>
> When the <div> DOM node is added to the screen, React will call your ref callback with the DOM node as the argument. When that <div> DOM node is removed, React will call your ref callback with null. 
>  
>  
> React will also call your ref callback whenever you pass a different ref callback. In the above example, `(node) => { ... }` is a different function on every render. When your component re-renders, the previous function will be called with null as the argument, and the next function will be called with the DOM node.

Since `useCallback` returns the same function reference each time when the dependency array is empty, the ref function is only called once (before the `<div>` is removed) in the example from the question.